# Slideshow not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've made a slideshow again but this, just like the previous one, doesn't seem to work. Could someone please explain why? I didn't make a fiddle because it seems to work on fiddle but not on my computer.

HTML

```
<html> 
<title>Simple slideshow</title>
<head>Hot Air Balloons All Over The World
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fadein.css">
<script src="slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
        <img src="HA balloon.jpg" width="600px" height="400px" title="Image credit:">
        <img src="HA balloons.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA balloon1.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA balloon2.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow
{
position: relative;
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
}

#slideshow img
{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
 }
```

JS

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('#slideshow :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('#slideshow');}, 
  3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to included jQuery to your header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add jQuery inside your header.
JSfiddle has jQuery included so it works there.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to refer jquery in your code. Include this to your `head` tag,

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Your html should look like

```
<html> 
<title>Simple slideshow</title>
<head>Hot Air Balloons All Over The World
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fadein.css">
<script src="slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
        <img src="HA balloon.jpg" width="600px" height="400px" title="Image credit:">
        <img src="HA balloons.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA balloon1.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA balloon2.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
        <img src="HA.jpg" width="600px" height="400px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anoop. I just tried your line of code and it works too.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code work I had to remove the script tags in the .js file. So anyone using this code you have to refer to jquery in your header in the HMTL file and you have to remove the  tags like I just said.